# Comparing values in two dictionaries in python from two different lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This is a small part of my program, but basically so far I have looked through two txt files and compared them to a main txt file with a key of words. For each of the first two txt files (txt file 1 & txt file 2), I found the frequencies of words from the main txt file and put the words and their frequencies of txt file 1 & txt file 2 into two separate dictionaries, wordfreq and wordfreq2.

Now I would like to compare the frequencies of the words from these two lists. If a the key in wordfreq has a greater value than the same key in wordfreq2, I would like to add that word to anotherdict1, and vice versa.

```
anotherdict1 = {}
anotherdict2 = {}


for key in wordfreq.keys():
    if key in wordfreq2.keys() > key in wordfreq.keys():
        anotherdict2.update(wordfreq2)

for key in wordfreq2.keys():
    if key in wordfreq.keys() > key in wordfreq2.keys():
        anotherdict1.update(wordfreq)

print (wordfreq)
print (wordfreq2)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is updating `anotherdict2` with `wordfreq2` (and the same for dict1). That means that every key/value in `wordfreq2` will be the same in `anotherdict2`. What you should be doing, however, is just adding that particular key/value pair. In addition, your `if` check is comparing two booleans. that is, `key in wordfreq2.keys()` will result in True or False, not the value itself. You should be using `wordfreq2[key]`. Here's how I would do it:

```
for key, wordfreq_value in wordfreq.items():
    wordfreq2_value = wordfreq2[key]
    if wordfreq2_value > wordfreq_value:
        anotherdict2[key] = wordfreq2_value
    else:
        anotherdict[key] = wordfreq_value
```